# When I select a row in a factbox how can I get the record?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central, businesscentral

Using a Chronus purchase invoices:

[image]

I'm interested in modifying the "Incoming Document Files" textbox.

When I select a file, I want to display it into another factbox, so my first step is trying to read the record that I've selected.

In this case, I've selected the file PLIMON_TSK0007. So if I click on the file PLIMON_TSK0008 it will change and the selected file it will be the PLIMON_TSK0008:

[image]

How can I use that event? Or how can I get the record when I select a new row?

I'm trying with this code:

```
pageextension 51101 "IncomingDoc.Attach.FactBoxExt" extends "Incoming Doc. Attach. FactBox"//193
{
    trigger OnAfterGetRecord()
    begin
    end;

    trigger OnAfterGetCurrRecord()
    begin
    end;
}
```

But it will break the factbox, when I select a new row it disappears:

[image]

That's how it looks when loading that code and selecting TSK0008...

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing else in this extension? There must be something missing. A page extension with an empty trigger does not break factboxes usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link one `FactBox` to another through the [`Provider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/properties/devenv-provider-property) property.

Consider `page A` to which we add `page B` and `page C` as FactBoxes.
We can then link `page C` to the selected record on `page B` like this:

```
page 50000 A
{
    ...
    
    layout
    {
        area(Content)
        {
            group(Records)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
        area(FactBoxes) {
            part(B;B)
            {
                ...
            }
            part(C;C) {
                Provider = B;
                SubPageLink = ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your case you would need to add your custom `FactBox` to the `Purchase Invoices` page through a `pageextension` and the set the `Provider` to the `Incoming Document Files FactBox`.

Comment: Many thanks this helped me a lot solving a headache, thanks <3